# Java formatting output

Tags: java, format, tostring, pow

I am not experienced in Java at all and am using a text editor to write code so I can't see what the problem is (I am running from command line)
I see the error and know what it is but I have no idea how to fix it

```
System.out.print(String.format("%7d", Math.pow(n,2).toString()));
```

I also tried without the `.toString()` 
Basically if I print only n it works, but the power function gives me an error probably because of return types, but pow should return a double and the string format %7d is probably also double right?

Comment: What's the error? You most likely want %7f rather than d (integer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong format specifier.. `%d` is used for integer.

`Math.pow()` returns primitive `double` on which you cannot invoke `toString()` method.

Try using `%7s` which is for `String`, and convert your primitive double value to `Wrapper type`: -

```
String.format("%7s", Double.valueOf(Math.pow(n,2)).toString())
```

---

But, you don't need to convert your argument to `String`, you can directly use `double value` with `%f`: -

```
String.format("%.3f", Math.pow(n,2));
```

Comment: @BheshGurung Yeah. I just did that to show OP how toString() should be invoked. Edited code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to use `f` instead of `d` without the `toString`. If you actually were able to do `toString` (as Quoi points out, you cannot do from a primitive), it would make it impossible to use `Formatter`s that expect the used `Number` object (`Double` in your case).

This is the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) that [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) uses.

Answer (score 0):

`Math#pow(double,double)` returns primitive double value you can not call `toString` method.
Use f instead of d, and d is for a decimal integer.

```
 System.out.format("%7f", Math.pow(n,2));
```

Better start with Eclipse or any other editor to write code.

Answer (score 0):

problem lies with `toString` method. You have given format specifier `%7d` that means `integer`. You can't print string in place of it.

Answer (score 0):

The Right Format for double is %f not %d so modify your code to:

```
 System.out.print(String.format("%7f",  Math.pow(n,2)));
```

see also :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568345/java-methodoverloading-error-with-double-values)